# Testing Room Migration. Cannot find the schema file in the assets folder

Tags: android, migration, android-room, android-testing

**My build.gradle file, I'm using kapt rather than java's annotation processor**

```
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        kapt {
            arguments {
                arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
            }
        }


    }
    sourceSets {

        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
```

**My RoomDatase base class with the exportSchema set to true**

```
@Database(entities = [DB_Open::class],version = 4, exportSchema = true)
```

**The database scheme get's exported and saved as a json file**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Iew.png

**But I still get this error for my migration tests**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find the schema file in the assets folder. Make sure to include the exported json schemas in your test assert inputs. See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schema for details. Missing file: com.crop2cash.gather.data.GatherDatabase/1.json
at androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper.loadSchema(MigrationTestHelper.java:320)
at androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper.createDatabase(MigrationTestHelper.java:152)
at com.crop2cash.gather.MigrationsTest.migrate1to2(MigrationsTest.kt:29)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
```

**I have tried all the stackoverflow solutions here like:**

```
sourceSets {

        getByName("debug").assets.srcDirs(files(projectDir, "schemas"))
    }
```

```
    sourceSets {


        getByName("androidTest") {
            assets.srcDirs(files(projectDir, "schemas"))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: For me, it worked to use test.assets.srcDirs instead of androidTest.assets.srcDirs which led however to the the next problem, that Android Studio included the schema folder somehow into the classpath, and the TestClass was showing errors, although the gradle build worked. Still investigating...

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, one possible source of this issue is the stripping of assets during packaging, i.e., if you have something like the rule below. It seems like it should apply to the release build only, but, alas, it applies to debug as well and will remove your schema files from view.

```
buildTypes {

  debug {...}

  release {
    aaptOptions {
      ignoreAssetsPattern '!*.json'
    }
  }
}
```